# R append items to a list by looping through length of a value

Tags: r

I may be overcomplicating my attempt at this. I have many values to sort through, and for each value I want a list to get larger in size with specific values appended. For example, if the value inputted is 3, I want the list to be (0.001, 0.11, 0.22), and if the value inputted is 5, the list would be (0.001, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44).
Below is a very simplified version of my code that I hope is reproducible and makes sense.

```
list_legth = function(value) {
  list <- c(0.001, 0.11)
  if (value = 5) {
    list <- append(list, c(0.22, 0.33, 0.44))
  }else if (value = 4) {
    list <- append(list, c(0.22, 0.33))
  }
  return(list)
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a loop such that list items are added until the value is reached, so the function does not get so repetitive as the actual version would be very long. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something along the lines of `function(value) head(c(0.001, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44), value))` ? There may be more natural ways to express what you want, depending on where this `list` and these `c(0.22, 0.33, 0.44)` etc come from or what they mean.

Comment: Also, `list` is not a good name for a variable in R because it is the name of an important class.

Comment: How are these values `c(0.001, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44)` created? You could simply return a subset, like `list <- c(0.001, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44)` and `return(list[1:value])`.

Comment: What happens when the value is 10?, .1010?

Comment: @MartinGal the values are for plotting node positions for plotly sankey charts,  and they are quite complicated with about 40 positions each, and I have 20 plots. Edit: your solution worked perfectly! Thank you so much

Comment: @dcarlson The max value is actually 9, which is set at 0.88, but in theory 10 would be 0.99

Comment: @GeorgeSavva list isn't the name of the actual object, just the dummy code I made for this post, but I now realize it was quite a poor choice, I'll remember that in the future.